# How is neo4j persistence implemented?

Tags: persistence, neo4j

How is neo4j persistence of nodes and relations implemented? How are indexes handled?

Comment: there is some hints about how persistence is implemented in this blog post http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1396301953/neo4j-internals?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: There is a serie of blogpost by a neo4j contributor http://digitalstain.blogspot.fr/2010_10_01_archive.html. IIRC it's a linked list, with buffer management and in memory locks. It has no particular datastructure.

Answer (score 9):

**On indexes:** 
`Neo4j` does not have indexes on it's own. It only has an interface called `IndexerService`, that is implemented by `Lucene` (for example), which is quite fast and handles exact and full-text searches quickly, but does not support any-search.

It's easy to index nodes in `neo4j`, you just call the function index(node, key, value); and it's indexed.

Not sure about *how* persistence is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they use their own storage implementation. Look around org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store package.